# For Loop through Named Range cells names

Tags: excel, vba

This is the scenario:

if a checkbox (SamePObx) is selected, i want to loop through a named range and verify that there is at least one value present in the cells, but the cell that contains a value cannot be named "PO_Cmt". If all the cells are blank then a msgbox pops up.

```
    If Sheet1.SamePObx.Value = True Then 'if checkbox is selected
        For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("SamePO")
            'if the cell is blank and isn't name PO_Cmt
            If (cell.Value <> "") And (cell.Name <> "PO_Cmt") Then
                x = x + 1 'one PO is present
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell

        'if no POs present, flag
         If x = 0 Then
             MsgBox "Please provide the necessary PO#(s)"
             GoTo cont
     End If
```

the issue i'm running into is a runtime error of 1004. this line is the issue:

```
If (cell.Value <> "") And (cell.Name <> "PO_Cmt") Then
```

Comment: change `For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("SamePO")` to `For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("SamePO").Cells`

Comment: The issue is with `cell.Name`. If "PO_Cmt" is a named range, then you will need to loop through the .Names collection and compare to the current cell.

Comment: Try using `cell.Name.Name`

Comment: Kyle can you please explain further?

Comment: PO_Cmt is the named range that i am looking to skip over when looping through each cell in the Same_PO range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Sheet1.SamePObx.Value = True Then 'if checkbox is selected

    x = Application.CountA(Sheet1.Range("SamePO"))

    If Range("PO_Cmt").Value <> "" Then x = x - 1

    'if no POs present, flag
     If x = 0 Then
         MsgBox "Please provide the necessary PO#(s)"
         GoTo cont
     End If
 End If
```